# Integer conversion with Console.ReadLine()

Tags: c#, type-conversion

To read an integer from user input, you can use:

```
int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

But why won't the following work?

```
int number = (int) Console.ReadLine();
```

What's the difference between `Convert.ToInt32` and casting with `(int)`?

Comment: Do you understand what a cast is (in programming terms)?

Comment: when you explicitly convert from a double to a int for exmple.Right?

Comment: There is a huge difference between *casting* and *parsing* (which you need to use). See my answer for more information @Daniel :)

Comment: I updated my answer with some further information.

Comment: possible duplicate of Stack Overflow [difference between Convert.ToInt32 and (int)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1608801/1768232)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**There is no way to cast a `System.String` to a `System.Int32`**

---

Unlike many other languages (e.g. PHP or JavaScript), C# is *strongly typed*. This means numbers (`int` in your case), and strings are two very different things. One cannot be cast to the other, because the C# compiler has no idea of how to make an implicit conversion between the two types. In a *loosly typed* language there are no *real* types, the compiler usually makes an educated *guess* about which type your variable has.

So, **casting** is for when you have a type that "may be" another type. You may for instance have an integer [boxed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx) as an `object`. In this case it is perfectly legal to write `int number = (int)someObject;` but you need to know *beforehand* that `someObject` can be cast to an integer, otherwise an `InvalidCastException` will be thrown at runtime.

You can also "cast" a type to (one of) its base-type(s), this commonly referred to as down-casting. For example: `var enumerable = (IEnumerable<string>)new List<string>();`. This however, is usually done *implicitly* in method calls, there are no common use-cases where you *explicitly* have to down-cast a type.

It's important to note that down-casting will not "convert" a type. My variable named `enumerable` in the above example is still a `List<string>`. The difference is that it is now *boxed* as a `IEnumerable<string>`. You can [unbox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx) your list via a new cast: `var list = (List<string>)enumerable;` or via the [`as`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx)-keyword if you are using a [reference-type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx) (class).

C# also supports casting between the different number types. For instance a `System.Decimal` or a `System.Double` can be cast to a `System.Int32`. But the decimals will get [truncated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.truncate(v=vs.110).aspx). For instance `int truncatedPI = (int)Math.PI;` will give you `3`. But as far as i know; this is just compiler-magic.

What you need to look into is something called *parsing*.

---

**Parsing** is the mechanism in which you have a value, that is not in the desired type (commonly a string) and *[parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing)* it to the type you want, either by using a built-in parser or by writing your own parser.

Most of the common [value-types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx) (structs and enums) in .NET have built-in static `Parse`-methods.

For integers: `int.Parse("15")`, for dates: `DateTime.Parse("2015-08-02 00:00")` and so on. These are built-in parsers, which are included in the .NET framework.

`Console.ReadLine` returns a string which cannot be implicitly converted to a integer by casting (boxing or unboxing). To solve your problem you need to use one of the *parsing-methods* mentioned above.

In your case `int number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());` would most likely suffice. But be careful, if you enter something like `"HELLO"` in your console-application, `int.Parse` will throw a `FormatException` since what you have entered cannot be interpreted by the parser.

This is where `TryParse` and `TryParseExact`, come in. They are usually more viable alternatives for handling user input.

---

As a general rule — try to avoid `Convert.To[Type]` when parsing strings. [These are generally just "lazy" implementations of the `Parse` method anyways](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,1112). Using the parsing methods mentioned above comes with more options, better scalability and also prompts the programmer with more precise information of what is going on in your code.

Answer (score 1):

That is because no explicit or implicit conversion exists between those two types in .NET framework. In other words explicit conversion operator is not overloaded in string class. More on converting strings to numbers in C# is in this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397679.aspx). Also read about [casting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

This might help understand why this doesn't work.

"Hi " + "there" = "Hi there", right?

1 + 3 = 4

What does "Hi " + 2 = ?

It makes no sense.

Since Console.ReadLine returns a string, the language has no way of knowing whether you're going to enter a number or not.  So it requires you to instead make an explicit statement that you're going to turn the input into a number, and that's what int.Parse does.  Convert calls this method - but like said above it's not as precise as calling Parse.